# Setting up two seperate stores that share the same inventory

Tags: magento-enterprise, multistore, extensions

We have 2 stores in Magento, one for wholesale and one for retail. Both stores sell the same products, except the wholesale store will be selling only one category of the overall products.

We want the inventory to be **shared between the two stores**, except they are totally independent of each other.

Just to explain a scenario:

If I have 100 of the same product available, I want the 100 to be available in both wholesale AND retail stores (Lets say 70 are available in the wholesale store, and 30 in the retail store).  If a wholesale buyer purchases 30 in the wholesale store, immediately only 70 will be available in **both** stores, leaving 40 available in the wholesale store and 30 will still be left in the retail store.

We're currently on `Magento Enterprise ver. 1.12.0.1`

What extensions would be needed to set this up, or can Magento do this by default?

Comment: How many seconds have you thought about simply googling the question ;) ?

Comment: @simonthesorcerer I did! It hasn't really helped as it's kind of a strange idea in theory. I just saw your answer now I'm going to take a look at it!

Comment: I don't think so actually, I think it's quite usual. Anyway, I really  hope my answer sheds some light ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a magento default functionality. You would set different root categories for the two websites you would be creating. The stock is automatically shared unless you take actions to make magento behave different.

Comment: Now technically they wouldn't be two websites. They would be on the same URL and would only be separated by going to the domain.com/wholesale store. Would this still work?

Comment: Yes. Look user system>stores. The magento concept of websites is designed for cases like this, I guess, and they also can run on a domain path. Based on the amount of differentiation you wish (prices, tax settings, customers shared/not shared), you should decide if you want to create a new website or only a new store view, but the "own categories" feature clearly means "website" imho

Comment: What I meant by the category selection part of my original question was that, say we have 3 categories of products in the retail store, only 1 of those 3 will be used in the wholesale store. So that's why I believe making a new store should work.

Comment: Just read your other question. Thanks for accepting here, sorry I could not help